# How to make Multiple Search in column?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code when I search for `Juan Pedro Cruz` nothing appears. But if I search only for `juan`, it does appear.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["btnssrch1"])){ 
  $cno1 = $_POST["ssrch1"];

$p = mysqli_query($link,"select * from patient 
                         where PatientId like '%$cno1%' 
                         or FirstName like '%$cno1%' 
                         or MiddleName like '%$cno1%'  
                         or LastName like '%$cno1%'");
  }
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, as per tradition, you should accept the answer which you find most useful by clicking green check mark left side of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to something like below, which concentrates the full name and then compare the same with like, assuming `PatientId` is numerical,

```
$p = mysqli_query($link,"select * from patient where CONCAT(FirstName,' ',MiddleName,' ',LastName) like '%{$cno1}%'");
```

This won't create any problem if you are just learning in local machine, but in production, always sanitize user inputted data and never trust user data.

Comment: You are damn fast! Grrr... `:P`

Answer (score 2):

A few pointers for you:

1. Try to sanitize the inputs.

   ```
   $cno1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["ssrch1"]);
   ```
2. Since you are using multiple columns, your SQL should be like:

   ```
   WHERE CONCAT(`FirstName`, ' ', `MiddleName`, ' ', `LastName`) LIKE '%{$cno1}%'
   ```